# Twilio studio, initial sms message

Tags: twilio

In twilio studio, I'm trying to create a workflow to send an initial text if the person has never sent us a message before. I have already setup auto responses, but I can't get the program to check whether the person has “subscribed” or not. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Messages Resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource#read-multiple-message-resources) and include the optional parameter of the incoming message from number.  Check the response back from the API call and look for the body property.

If they've messaged you in the past you'll get a response and you'll see what they messaged you.

You could do this using a [Twilio function](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions) and the [run function](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/run-function) widget or just use the [http get](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/http-request) widget and then use a [split based on](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/split-based-on) widget to make a branch based upon the returned JSON.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to create your own database to capture that metadata (firstContact=false or something similar) if they have previously responded and then respond with the appropriate message.

You can save this data to your CRM or a database, POSTing via the HTTP Request Widget or Run Function Widget (where you keep their opt-in records) and then refer to it when making an outbound response or REST API Trigger call, to determine if they responded previously.

It is important to make sure you have [customer opt-in](https://www.google.com/search?q=Twilio%20Messaging%20Policy) before initiating an outbound SMS.